# Custom sort a list by fixing the first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list

```
[25, 35, 54, 70, 68, 158, 78, 11, 18, 12]
```

I want to sort this list by fixing the first element i.e: if I fix 35 the sorted list should look like

```
[35, 54, 68, 70, 78, 158, 11, 12, 18, 25]
```

If I fix 158 as the first element the sorted list should look like

```
[158, 11, 12, 18, 25, 35, 54, 68, 70, 78]
```

basically I want to fix the first element and the rest should be in sorted order, if there is a number that is lesser than the first element is found it should not go before first element. Is there a builtin function available for this in Python?

Comment: If this is for something like an in-place quicksort, there are lots of existing solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a key function like:

#### Code:

```
def sorter(threshold):
    def key_func(item):
        if item >= threshold:
            return 0, item
        return 1, item

    return key_func
```

This works by returning a tuple such that the numbers above threshold will sort below the numbers under the threshold.

#### Test Code:

```
data = [25, 35, 54, 70, 68, 158, 78, 11, 18, 12]
print(sorted(data, key=sorter(70)))
```

#### Results:

```
[70, 78, 158, 11, 12, 18, 25, 35, 54, 68]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list and then recover the index of the element with `lst.index` to pivot it.

### Code

```
def pivot_sort(lst, first_element):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    index = lst.index(first_element)

    return lst[index:] + lst[:index]
```

### Example

```
lst = [25, 35, 54, 70, 68, 158, 78, 11, 18, 12]

print(pivot_sort(lst , 70))
# prints: [70, 78, 158, 11, 12, 18, 25, 35, 54, 68]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
a = [25, 35, 54, 70, 68, 158, 78, 11, 18, 12]
a.sort()
index = a.index(35)
a = a[index:] + [:index]

print(a) #[35, 54, 68, 70, 78, 158, 11, 12, 18, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast and simple **`numpy`** solution:

```
def numpy_roll(arr, elem):
    arr = np.sort(arr)
    return np.roll(arr, len(arr)-np.argwhere(arr==elem)[0])

x
# array([17, 30, 16, 78, 54, 83, 92, 16, 73, 47])

numpy_roll(x, 16)
# array([16, 16, 17, 30, 47, 54, 73, 78, 83, 92])
```

Answer (score 0):

Combined use of [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

**Code**:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def pivot_sort(lst, pivot):
    sorted_lst = sorted(lst)
    return list(islice(cycle(sorted_lst), sorted_lst.index(pivot), 2*len(sorted_lst)-lst.index(pivot)))


lst = [25, 35, 54, 70, 68, 158, 78, 11, 18, 12]
pivot = 70

print(pivot_sort(lst, pivot))

# [70, 78, 158, 11, 12, 18, 25, 35, 54, 68]
```