# Custom sort a list of ordered dict by fixing one of the key's values as first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of ordereddict

```
[OrderedDict([('song', 'Hoses'), ('lyric', 'crea'), ('Music', 'reut'), ('BGM', 'DJU'),  ('Totalsecs', 223.457894215)])
,OrderedDict([('song', 'Goses'), ('lyric', 'recrea'), ('Music', 'reutser'), ('BGM', 'DJS'),  ('Totalsecs', 158.514553868968)])
,OrderedDict([('song', 'reoses'), ('lyric', 'arecrea'), ('Music', 'hiureut'), ('BGM', 'VJU'),  ('Totalsecs', 11.879461215421)])
,OrderedDict([('song', 'reteoses'), ('lyric', 'makuri'), ('Music', 'reut'), ('BGM', 'DJU'),  ('Totalsecs', 123.513353868968)]
)]
```

i want to sort them based on the totalsecs key by fixing first element, i.e  in the above list of ordereddict, i want to fix  `('Totalsecs', 158.514553868968)` as the first element so that the rest of them are sorted below that so the list of ordered dict will become

```
[OrderedDict([('song', 'Goses'), ('lyric', 'recrea'), ('Music', 'reutser'), ('BGM', 'DJS'),  ('Totalsecs', 158.514553868968)])
 ,OrderedDict([('song', 'Hoses'), ('lyric', 'crea'), ('Music', 'reut'), ('BGM', 'DJU'),  ('Totalsecs', 223.457894215)])
,OrderedDict([('song', 'reoses'), ('lyric', 'arecrea'), ('Music', 'hiureut'), ('BGM', 'VJU'),  ('Totalsecs', 11.879461215421)])
,OrderedDict([('song', 'reteoses'), ('lyric', 'makuri'), ('Music', 'reut'), ('BGM', 'DJU'),  ('Totalsecs', 123.513353868968)]
)]
```

basically I want to fix the first element and the rest should be in sorted order, if there is a number that is lesser than the first element is found it should not go before first element. Do we have any built in function for this in python? I have asked a similar kind of question for lists, but this if for list of ordereddict

Comment: How are elements apart from the first sorted in your result? 223.45 -> 11.87 -> 123.51 does not appear to be sorted.

Comment: in an increasing order the number next to 158 is 223 and if there is a number that is lesser than the first element is found it should not go before first element, so the 11 is next to 223 and 123 is next to 11, numbers above threshold need to be sorted below the numbers under the threshold.

Comment: Seems very similar to your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652847/custom-sort-a-list-by-fixing-the-first-element)

Comment: @RoadRunner yes that is what i have mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to perform your two sorts separately and then combine.

Given a list `A` of `OrderedDict` objects:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# retrieve threshold
threshold = A[1]['Totalsecs']

# sort above threshold
sort1 = sorted((i for i in A if i['Totalsecs'] >= threshold), key=itemgetter('Totalsecs'))

# sort below threshold
sort2 = sorted((i for i in A if i['Totalsecs'] < threshold), key=itemgetter('Totalsecs'))

# combine into one list
res = sort1 + sort2

print(res)

[OrderedDict([('song', 'Goses'), ('lyric', 'recrea'), ('Music', 'reutser'),
              ('BGM', 'DJS'), ('Totalsecs', 158.514553868968)]),
 OrderedDict([('song', 'Hoses'), ('lyric', 'crea'), ('Music', 'reut'),
              ('BGM', 'DJU'), ('Totalsecs', 223.457894215)]),
 OrderedDict([('song', 'reoses'), ('lyric', 'arecrea'), ('Music', 'hiureut'),
              ('BGM', 'VJU'), ('Totalsecs', 11.879461215421)]),
 OrderedDict([('song', 'reteoses'), ('lyric', 'makuri'), ('Music', 'reut'),
              ('BGM', 'DJU'), ('Totalsecs', 123.513353868968)])]
```